# Strange event when evaluating 2D Sage Code

Tags: sage

After installing sage on my Macbook Pro (10.6.8), I tried the following code, which worked.

[image]

Then I tried:

[image]

Yikes! What happened? Any thoughts?

D.

Answer (score 2):

You redefined `x`.

```
P = polygon([[1,2],[5,6],[5,0]])
Q = polygon([(-x,y) for x,y in P[0]])
print x
```

yields `5.0`.  That's why `var('x')` worked, it redefined `x` back.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, but not sure why.

[image]